# How to Implement AJAX to call for web service

Tags: php, ajax

I have created a simple PHP interface for the user to key in the country name to find out about the current weather.

This is my php first page,

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<body>

  <h3>Current Weather</h3>
  <form action="currentWeather.php" method="post">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Country Name:</td>
        <td>:
          <input type="text" name="countryName" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="right">
          <input type="submit">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

After the user key in the country, it will display the weather condition of the country on another page.

```
<?php
        $countryName = $_POST["countryName"];

        $uri = "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v2/weather.ashx?q=" . $countryName . "&format=xml&num_of_days=5&key=ded6d9349e5334a39e2e2f26fd996";
        $weather = simplexml_load_file($uri);

        foreach ($weather->current_condition as $weatherinfo):
            $temp = $weatherinfo->temp_C;
            $icon = $weatherinfo->weatherIconUrl;
        endforeach;

        echo '<h2>Display the temperature and weather Icon</h2>';
        echo 'Current Temprarture ' . $temp . ' C <br>';
        echo " <img src = $icon >";
        echo '<br>';
 ?>
```

[image]

The plan is once the user click on the submit button, the weather condition will appear at the bottom.

I tried to do some research but I did not found anything similar to my problem. I am currently calling a web service called world weather online, not very sure on how to implement AJAX with it.

Comment: I'm not clear why you need AJAX if you're sending the country via POST and displaying the results on another page...

Comment: Are you trying to avoid going to another page, and do it all in the same page with AJAX. What efforts have you made so far?

Comment: As you say, you will need an ajax call to do that. In this way you will not be redirected to an other page.

Comment: But i do not know how to use ajax

Comment: @Raymond Then you should go search for tutorials on how to use AJAX. SO is not a tutorial service.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
....
function myFunction() {
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
            setTimeout("callback()", 3000);
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", "url", true);
    xmlHttp.send();
};
function callback() {
    //xmlHttp.responseText
};
....
```

Comment: His question is about the client side. His PHP code already looks like it works.

Comment: @Barmar, you are right. Just share some idea if want to use PHP instead of Ajax.

Comment: How is your answer better than just the one line call to `simplexml_load_file()` that does all the work?